# C#: Can you completely wipe the console window?

Tags: c#, console-application, ansi-escape

Before you mark this question as a duplicate, I have a very specific problem with the `Console.Clear()` method. When I clear the console with this method, it just "pushes" all the output up until there's nothing left to see (i.e. prints a bunch of newlines). This works well with most of my applications but it doesn't work with ANSI escape codes that change the position of the cursor. E.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine("How are you");
Console.Clear();
Console.Write("\x1b[0;0HI'm fine");
```

This would just print `I'm fine` on the first line, that you can't actually see anymore (because it's been "pushed" up) instead of the "new" home position. I am using Cygwin terminal.

Please let me know how to "properly" clear the console window or set the cursor position.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried writing an empty line after clearing to reset the cursor? or explicitly setting the cursor position?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann No, that didn't work unfortunately, but I found it works when you use the escape code for clearing the screen (`Console.Write(\x1b[2J)` instead of `Console.Clear()`). Still thank you for the reply